# COLLATE NOCASE in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've run a sql query in sqlite database using COLLATE NOCASE such that it ignores either the user input is uppercase or lowercase and retrieve the data.But it's not working actually. Place1 and Place2 has data like Bagmati, Basantapur but when the user inputs Place1 as bagmati then it doesnot give the data.

```
public String getTaxiDistance(String name, String depart){
        String [] columns = {"fare"};

        c = db.rawQuery("select Distance from TaxiFinalData where Place1 = '"+name+"' COLLATE NOCASE and Place2 = '"+depart+"' COLLATE NOCASE or Place1 = '"+depart+"' COLLATE NOCASE and Place2 = '"+name+"'COLLATE NOCASE", new String[]{});


        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while(c.moveToNext()){

            String employyename = c.getString(0);


            buffer.append(employyename+"");
        }

        return buffer.toString();

    }
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/cdf2f/2). Show the actual values of `name` and `depart`, and the table row that you think should match.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert everything to uppercase in your request, this should do the trick !

```
c = db.rawQuery("select Distance from TaxiFinalData where upper(Place1) = upper('"+name+"') and upper(Place2) = upper('"+depart+"') or upper(Place1) = upper('"+depart+"') and upper(Place2) = upper('"+name+"')", new String[]{});
```

Answer (score 0):

Aware of that upper() and lower() in Sqlite work only with ASCII codes table